# C Array declaration; Excess elements in array initializer

Tags: c

## Reproduce

```c
int array[2] = {1,2,3};
```

## What happens

```c
printf("%d",array[2]);
```

Dose c just append all three values to the stack?
As it seems it dosen´t but why?

Comment: What do you want to do? `int array[2] = {1,2,3};` is wrong. The 2 in the array initialization must correspond to the number of elements in the array or you will get "warning: excess elements in array initializer". Also, the first element of an array in C starts at 0. So if you want the last element of a 3 element array, you have to call `array[2]`.

Comment: "it dosen´t but why?" Why would it? You explicitely told the compiler to reserve some memory for 2 elements. That is what you get. And everyone (even the compiler) knows that 3 elements don't fit into place for 2.

Comment: Just in case you don't do that yet: always enable all warnings the compiler offers. `-Wall` on gcc.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, note that the third element of the array would be `array[2]`, not `array[3]`.

The compiler will give a warning about having too many elements in the initializer:

```
warning: excess elements in array initializer
    5 |  int array[2] = {1,2,3};
      |                      ^
note: (near initialization for ‘array’)
```

If you ignore the warning and run the code anyway, the value of `array[2]` will be a random value -- whatever happened to be at that location.

Comment: thanks, but why wouldn't c just write the third element to the memory. And is there any reasonable case where the initialisation and the array length would mismatch

Comment: @Hu1buerger there are 2 cases for a mismatch: 1) You provide less initializers than the array size. That is fine and the remaining elements are intitilized to 0. 2) You provide more values than fit into the array. That is just a bug and needs to be fixed.

Comment: What about leaving out the size in this case? (case of possible mismatch)

Comment: Re “the value of `array[2]` will be a random value -- whatever happened to be at that location”: That is not true and should not be taught to students. The C standard does not define the behavior. As an example, I put `int a[2] = { 1, 2, 3 }; printf("%d\n", a[2]); extern void foo(int *); foo(a);` in `main` and `void foo(int *a) { printf("%d\n", a[2]); }` in a separate file, compiled with Apple Clang 11.0 with `-O3`, linked, and executed. The output was “-404403648” and “-404403664”…

Comment: … Looking at the generated assembly, in `main`, the compiler did not put anything in the RSI register used for passing the second argument to `printf`. So what was printed was a value that the run-time initialization code left in RSI (the value of `argv`, I expect, since that is the second argument to `main`). In the separate code, the compiler loaded something from memory to be printed, so that did get whatever was in memory after `a`. So, while `a[2]` appear to be what is in memory after `a` in some uses, it is not in other uses, and it may even have different “values” in the same program.

Comment: I'm not sure what point Eric is making -- I just meant that the value returned for `array[2]` is unpredictable, or `undefined`, as the standard says.

Comment: @ChrisDennis: (a) The answer says the value will be “whatever happened to be at that location”. That is false. The value may come from somewhere else. (b) The answer indicates the expression `array[2]` has a value. That is also false. Per the C standard, not just the value, but the entire behavior of the program is undefined. The expression might have no value at all because the program does something entirely different than evaluating whatever expression or statement or function this appeared in. This answer teaches students wrong things about C.

Answer (score 1):

Having excess items in the initializer is a *constraint violation*:

> **6.7.9 Initialization**
> ...
> **Constraints**
> 2 No initializer shall attempt to provide a value for an object not contained within the entity
> being initialized.

<sup>*[C 2011 Online Draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)*</sup>

The compiler is required to issue at least one diagnostic if it detects any constraint violations.

The array is only defined for elements `array[0]` and `array[1]` - attempting to read `array[2]` leads to undefined behavior, so the result is not predictable or repeatable.

Comment: A correct implication is “undefined behavior, so the behavior is not defined by the C standard” or “undefined behavior, so the result cannot be relied on based on the C standard alone.” The implication “undefined behavior, so the result is not predictable or repeatable” is false. I have repeatedly observed Clang omit a computation that would put an undefined value in a register (such as a load from memory or a calculation), and I predict it will continue to do so in the version I have. The concept “not asserted by certain rules” is different from “cannot be predicted” or “cannot be repeated.”